# Java | okhttp3 | how to test expired token

Tags: java, mockito, token, okhttp

I am a tester and want to check: when I call endpoint with expired token (obtained from different endpoint) I obtain code 401 however I cannot manage that somehow and Im constantly getting 200.

When I get token at endpoint **A** I have response like follows:

```
{
   "token": [token],
   "expiry": 1658832662994
}
```

I have tried to fake callout to next method at some time however even though the time do is put to future (I have tested with printouts to console) I still cannot receive 401. Has anyone had alike issue? How can I call my okhttp3 method after my token has expired without making my tests last longer?

```
 public void myMethod {
        Clock clock = Clock
                .fixed(Instant
                        .parse(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'", Locale.US)
                                .format(new Date(timestampExpiry))
                        .plusSeconds(1), ZoneId.of("UTC"));

        Instant instant = Instant.now(clock);

        try (MockedStatic<Instant> mockedStatic = mockStatic(Instant.class)) {
            mockedStatic.when(Instant::now).thenReturn(instant);
            Instant now = Instant.now();

            [call out my okhttp3 method for my endpoint B using my token from endpoint A]
        }
    }
```

Comment: Obtain a token, save it, wait until it expires, and you have a token that expired in the past.

Comment: Usually the expiry time is also stored inside the token - at least from my experience with JWT (json web token) - but your token might be different.

Comment: @BalázsNémeth but that will make my tests last longer which I do not want

Comment: the first answer is the same... it won't make tests longer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can obtain a token once (manually?) and store it with your test code as resource. You could even set the computers date and time to some ancient point in time for just that single retrieval of the token.

Then use that stored token in that test - once it is too old, it will keep that property for all subsequent test executions.

To make it clear: don't obtain the "too old" token dynamically with every test execution, but use a pre-stored one.

Comment: Yeah, I can extract it once - You mean to hardcode once generated token in some config? 
Would that make my tests reliable for future changes?

Comment: Yes, I meant to hardcode it. This one test should not test anything else except the use of outdated tokens, so as the underlying token technology is not exchanged, you should be fine. And the signing key-pair could be changed so that the token is not accepted for another reason - this should be covered by another test, or a different error message from the service that consumes the token.

Comment: but then again: is the expiry date checking implemented by the code that you are testing or by a library that is used? If it is done by a library: do you want to test the libray??

Comment: Its implemented by the code, okay thx then Ill save it :) @cyberbrain

Comment: if you find the answer helpful, it would be nice if you mark it as solution and maybe even upvote it - this will help others with the same or similar questions to find that answer.

Comment: I cant upvote it as I have score under 15 (at least this is the info I get), but I „ticked” it :-) thanks again!